# android:cardView width is not matching to it's parent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

**Please Read Full**  - Well I don't know what's gone wrong here.
Each of the `CardView` Bottom is not matching to it's parent.!

I'm trying to add background to `RecyclerView` and make transparent background to `CardView`

**custom_row Code -**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="7.5dp"
        android:paddingTop="7.5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_movie" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.75"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/playList_name"
                    android:layout_width="240dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="SongName"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:textColor="#c1c1c1"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/album_artist"
                    android:layout_width="240dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/playList_name"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="ARTIST"
                    android:textColor="#a1a1a1"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/my_overflow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_grade" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView></LinearLayout>
```

And here's **song_fragment.xml -**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ansh.albums.Fragments.Songs">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Here's the Result which i got - 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms40v.jpg)

I don't know why each of the cardView is not matching to it's parent width at bottom?

Please help.!

Comment: try setting elevation to 0 inside cardView

Comment: It didn't helped @Aditi

Comment: you want to match card's height or width? you don't want the divider in between the cards?

Comment: Yeah i don't want dividers. I just want cardView to match it's width to parent.. As you can see the image, each cardView is shrinking at the bottom.! ( is my xml code is wrong? )  @anders

Comment: try removing `card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius"`

Comment: Wow it actually works @Anders . I did what you said. :) . Though I am confused why it's actually not working as i set cardCornerRadius to '0'. Do you have an explanation? ( and now dividers are showing.. how to remove them? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use try this to get ride of the bottom divider

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
```